# ViewController access the instance method in CCScene created by CocosBuilder?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder, ccscene

Let me give an example to illustrate:

e.g. in CocosBuilder, I have created a **Scene.ccbi** 
and its custom class **Scene** class

Inside **Scene header**, I have defined a method:

```
-(void) doSomething;
```

In **AppDelegate/ViewController**, I call CCBReader to create the CCScene:

```
CCScene* myScene = [CCBReader sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile:@"Scene.ccbi"];
```

i.e. Scene.m has its instance now.

In this point, how can AppDelegate/ViewController access the Scene 's **instance method**? for example, inside ViewController:

```
Scene *ccbinstrance; // this is the part I don't know to link Scene*
[cbbinstance doSomething];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems no one has a good answer for this. I have a dirty way to resolve this problem.
I create a static singleton object and store this reference of Scene.
And then it can be called by another viewController using that singleton object.

It's kind of dirty but work for me at the moment...